# Efficient implementation of a numbered window variable around given events

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset with continuous and a vector of "event" dates. I want to create a numbered windows variable for windows of a given length before and after each event. I have a working code, but it is ridiculously slow and I was wondering about the best way to increase its efficiency.

Below I put the code. I also have a function create_date_vector which keeps only dates which separated enough so that there is no overlap in the windows, which is more so that the example below runs (but obviously improvements on that are also welcome).

```
data <- data.frame(day = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2001-01-01"), by = "day"))

dates <- sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2001-01-01"), by = "day"), 30)

pre <- 3
post <- 3

create_date_vector <- function(dates, pre, post){
  
  t_dates_dif <- diff(dates)
  selected_dates <- c()
  
  for(i in 1:(length(t_dates_dif) - 1)){
    selected_dates <- c(selected_dates, (t_dates_dif[i] > pre + post) + (t_dates_dif[i+1] > pre + post))
  }
  return(dates[which(selected_dates == 2) + 1])
}

dates_chosen <- sort(create_date_vector(dates, pre, post))
```

The bit which really needs optimizing is the following code which creates the windows:

```
data$event <- NA
for(i in 1:length(dates_chosen)){
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(
      event = ifelse(day >= dates_chosen[i] - pre & day <= dates_chosen[i] + post, i, event)
    )
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows around the event dates can be created by *updating in a non-equi join* using a helper table

```
library(data.table)
# create helper table
events <- data.table(dates_chosen)[
  , `:=`(rn = .I, from = dates_chosen - pre, to = dates_chosen + post)]
# update in a non-equi join 
setDT(data)[events, on = .(day >= from, day <= to), event := rn][]
```

> ```
>             day event
>   1: 2000-01-01    NA
>   2: 2000-01-02    NA
>   3: 2000-01-03    NA
>   4: 2000-01-04    NA
>   5: 2000-01-05    NA
>  ---                 
> 363: 2000-12-28    NA
> 364: 2000-12-29    NA
> 365: 2000-12-30    NA
> 366: 2000-12-31    NA
> 367: 2001-01-01    NA
> ```

```
# show only updated rows
data[!is.na(event)]
```

> ```
>            day event
>  1: 2000-05-16     1
>  2: 2000-05-17     1
>  3: 2000-05-18     1
>  4: 2000-05-19     1
>  5: 2000-05-20     1
>  6: 2000-05-21     1
>  7: 2000-05-22     1
>  8: 2000-06-17     2
>  9: 2000-06-18     2
> 10: 2000-06-19     2
> 11: 2000-06-20     2
> 12: 2000-06-21     2
> 13: 2000-06-22     2
> 14: 2000-06-23     2
> 15: 2000-10-26     3
> 16: 2000-10-27     3
> 17: 2000-10-28     3
> 18: 2000-10-29     3
> 19: 2000-10-30     3
> 20: 2000-10-31     3
> 21: 2000-11-01     3
>            day event
> ```

The helper table is

```
events[]
```

> ```
>    dates_chosen rn       from         to
> 1:   2000-05-19  1 2000-05-16 2000-05-22
> 2:   2000-06-20  2 2000-06-17 2000-06-23
> 3:   2000-10-29  3 2000-10-26 2000-11-01
> ```

Comment: Very clever and super elegant! And 33x times faster! data.table for the win as always! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier with `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
create_date_vector2 <- function(dates, pre, post) {
      t1 <- diff(dates)      
      pre_post <- pre + post
      dates[which(((t1 > pre_post) + (dplyr::lead(t1) > pre_post)) == 2) + 1]
}
```

-testing

```
> create_date_vector2(dates, 3, 3)
[1] "2011-06-17" "2008-07-30" "2002-02-19"
```

-output from OP's function

```
> create_date_vector(dates, pre, post)
[1] "2011-06-17" "2008-07-30" "2002-02-19"
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to run about as fast, with some improvements sometimes. If I'm going to be honest, it's more the second part that needs optimizing ... Thank you for your answer though!